Is there any serious ongoing research into preventing the body from developing a tolerance to given drugs?
This question came to mind in the context of reading about the opioid epidemic. One of the factors that seemed to lead to the crisis getting out of control was the fact that over time people would develop a tolerance to the medications they were prescribed, requiring larger and larger doses to achieve the same effect.  Users of opioids recreationally would encounter the same issue, requiring increasingly strong drugs such as fentanyl to obtain the same high.
Given the issues that this behaviour of the human body causes, is there any ongoing research into limiting the ability of the body to develop a tolerance to particular classes of drugs? Is this even a problem which is tractable in principle?
I have tried to narrow the question down to a “class” of drugs (if I need to specify a class, then I guess opioids), just because I imagine that trying to limit your body’s ability to develop tolerances in general is ill advised.
